# Is there a name for this type of word problems?

Tags: terminology, solution-verification, mathematical-modeling, word-problem

I made up the following situation/problem but I'd like to know if they have an specific name so I can look for more examples.

> I buy a car for \$20,000 and during the first month it requires an amount of gas worth \$100. This cost doubles every month because the car is leaking. All the cars in existence cost the same and suffer the same problem. Every how many months is it worth to buy a new car rather than keep paying the amount of gas?

Also, I'd like to check if my approach is correct:

One solution that it occurs to me is that at the end of the ninth month, I would be paying \$25,600 in gas so that month would be an obvious moment to buy a new car, "reset" the cost of gas so that month I pay \$20,100 instead.

In terms of the function  that gives the cost based on the month:

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
f(1) = 20,100 \\
f(n) = 100\cdot2^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

Where I have solved for $ f(n) > 20,100 $ which gives me  $ n\approx8.65 $, i.e. the ninth month I'd be paying more than the first month already.

Do this word problem have a specific name? Also, is my approach correct?

Comment: Your solution could use a tad more justification (what if the numbers worked out so that buying a car more often to keep gas prices even lower could be viable? Why is this not so?), but other than that it looks fine. Great way to increase pollution though. Problems like this could be considered to fall under the realm of recurrence relations, though proving the solution is actually optimal likely falls under optimization theory (e.g. convex analysis)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understood your first point correctly but if I understood it properly is related to another concern with this situation: Even if the solution works out in the ninth month, I think there could be a calculation involving the accumulative cost of gas to determinate another good moment to buy the car. But didn't found to how fit it properly

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think I get it. For example, buying a car every month arguing that after X years the accumulative price paid in total is far lower than paying for a car every nine months?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply call it **calculus of interest** (with compound interests), but instead of calculation with money, you calculate with different items here.

From a business perspective, you could also view this problem as a **cost-benefit calculation**.